# Nuxt Routing on root "/" throws a 404

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

I am new to programming and just trying to understand some basics of nuxt. My local host returns a 404 with the error message "[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/"".

Also I have created two pages in /pages. Accessing them works.

I am particularly confused that the error points to the Vue router, I though the routing is handled with Nuxt? Also everything worked fine with the default nuxt view.

No clue where to look at.

Comment: Inded nuxt will auto create/generate your vue router.
But inside your folders pages you need start create a page ```index.vue``` for example and this page will be available on /.

if you create a page ```about.vue``` you will need to access it on /about.

Comment: Hello, I'd recommend always reading the documentation for whatever you are working on: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/routing

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty easy, just add an "index.vue" to your /pages.